# Using rotation gates instead of Grover

Tags: grovers-algorithm, unitarity, amplitude-amplification

I have a conceptual question about Grover's algorithm. In the textbook case, we always assume to have an oracle that singles out the correct states by giving them a negative phase. Then, we use phase flip operators to increase the amplitudes of these marked states. Basically, this amounts to a rotation from the bad states towards the good states, which we can write using a rotation matrix
$$ G =\begin{pmatrix} \cos2\theta & -\sin2\theta \\
                      \sin2\theta & \cos2\theta \end{pmatrix}, $$
starting from the initial state $|\psi\rangle = \sin\theta|\mathsf{good}\rangle + \cos\theta|\mathsf{bad}\rangle. $ Then this rotation procedure is repeated $t$ times until $G^t|\psi\rangle = \sin((2t+1)\theta)|\mathsf{good}\rangle+\cos((2t+1)\theta|\mathsf{bad}\rangle$, and so that $\sin((2t+1)\theta)$ is close to 1. These repetitions are what makes Grover a relatively expensive algorithm.

I was wondering if there can be a faster way, in case we know exactly which states we are looking for and all the amplitudes of our initial state $|\psi\rangle$. Is there a way of immediately constructing the rotation matrix $G^t$ and apply it to $|\psi\rangle$ via some unitary gates? I guess an easy way, would be to simply build a matrix like
$$ G' = \begin{pmatrix} \sin\theta & -\cos\theta \\
                      \cos\theta & \sin\theta \end{pmatrix}. $$
Is there any way of doing this more efficiently than Grover in an $n$-qubit system? How could one do that? Or in the converse case, why would it not be possible? I'm especially interested in the case where the initial state is not an equal superposition state, and where e.g. the good states already have a slightly higher probability than average.

Thank you for any leads!

Comment: you can always find a unitary operation sending an input to a given output, if that's what you're asking. The point of Grover's algorithm is that you can find a decomposition for that unitary in terms of "simple" ones that are easy to implement.

Comment: So are you saying that the reason Grover is generally used instead of rotation, e.g. using the $R$-matrices, is that it is actually more efficient to implement?

Comment: well, yes. Efficiency (in terms of number of gates required to perform the operation) is kinda the whole point of Grover's algorithm. If you don't care about efficiency, you can send any state to any other state via an appropriate unitary operation